# Angular 1 directive does not render inside a directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, custom-directive

I'm having issues with Angular directives.

My goal is to render a directive `mmContentRow` for each element in a scope using `ng-repeat`. That directive `mmContentRow` has a template where another directive `relativeDate` is rendered.

The problem is that `relativeDate` does not get rendered inside `mmContentRow`.
I've tried many solutions but nothing so far. Here is the code:

`parent.html`:

```
  <ul>
    <mm-content-row ng-repeat="report in selected.reports" date="report.reported_date"/>
  </ul>
```

`mm-content-row.js`

```
angular.module('inboxDirectives').directive('mmContentRow', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'mm-content-row.html',
    scope: {
      date: '=',
    }
  };
});
```

`mm-content-row.html`:

```
<li>
  <span>{{date}}</span>
  <relative-date date="{{date}}"></relative-date>
</li>
```

`relative-date.js`:

```
angular.module('inboxDirectives').directive('relativeDate', ['FormatDate', function(FormatDate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span>rendered something</span>',
    scope: {
      date: '=',
    }
  };
}]);
```

Example data:

```
{ selected: {reports: 
[{reported_date: 1508493112758}, {reported_date: 1508493101933}]
} }
```

Rendered output:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1508493112758</span>
    <relative-date date="1508493112758"></relative-date>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>1508493101933</span>
    <relative-date date="1508493101933"></relative-date>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Expected output:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1508493112758</span>
    <span>rendered something</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>1508493101933</span>
    <span>rendered something</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As far as I can see, the `relative-date` inside a directive inside `ng-repeat` doesn't get compiled. I expected Angular to automatically compile it, but it doesn't seem to happen. Should I explicitly tell Angular to compile `relative-date` inside `mmContentRow`?

Update: I've created a fiddle with simplified version of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cbrwizard/4e2r2o07/. Everything works there. Weird! I will post here an update if I figure the difference between the fiddle and my code.

Comment: Can you create simple example at jsfiddle to quicken finding resolution?

Comment: still scratching my head as to why did you need 2 custom directives which could have been done in one

Comment: @Mudassar I want to reuse `relativeDate` in other directives as well. In this example I've removed the implementation details so I understand where your question comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @appeiron's suggestion, I've created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cbrwizard/4e2r2o07/ which let me understand that the issue is in Angular, but in the project's code.

Turned out a template wasn't rendered directly, but instead some regex magic was used to parse the `html` file. Adding

`$compile($(element).contents())(scope)`

where `element` is an html file string was enough to make it work.